# How can I setup a bar chart in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to build a [bar chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560) in Google Data Studio equal to an existing bar chart that I have already built on Google Sheets sharing the same data.

Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pRnUyoHMJGP_WLTlIlA9r_u1a-DG4Esif63EHpkN8Wk/edit?usp=sharing)):

| Class | Total citations | Stocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 83.4 | 7 |
| 2 | 166.8 | 13 |
| 3 | 250.2 | 18 |
| 4 | 333.6 | 9 |
| 5 | 417 | 9 |
| 6 | 500.4 | 3 |
| 7 | 283.8 | 5 |
| 8 | 667.2 | 1 |
| 9 | 750.6 | 0 |
| 10 | 834 | 1 |

This is my chart on Google Data Studio: (I expected it to look like on Google Sheets, but it does not)

[image: Chart on Data Studio]

This is my chart in Google Sheets:

[image: Chart on Sheets]

How should I setup the chart on Google Data Studio to have the same look of the one on Google Sheets?

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/cbbcb5c8-67c4-482d-a5d5-452f44b821c0) report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bar chart in DataStudio is currently sorted on Stocks metric. 
You should sort it using Total citations Dimension to get the same look as that in Google sheets.
[You can find sort field here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdzRP.png)

Edited:
I created a same sheet using the data you showed and created a DS report as well.
here's a screenshot.
[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07fhT.png)

Just take Total citations as Dimension
Stocks as metric and
sort by Total citations (Increasing)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the chart being sorted by the metric, `Stocks` (aggregtion: [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212)) in descending order. Sorting data by the row order in Google Sheets can be achieved by using either the `Record Count` or `Class` field (the below uses the `Class` field to demonstrate):

| Description | Details |
| --- | --- |
| **Chart**: | [Column Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560) |
| **Dimension**: | `Total citations` |
| **Metric**: | `Stocks` |
| **Sort Field**: | `Class` |
| **Sort Order**: | Ascending |
| **Sort Aggregation**: | [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518) |

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5fb57cb5-5d90-4b3e-b27b-0d0735a5d847) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IlzyzUUspRoaa5QoN4gT8Js09J27jpWUileIUVySPM8/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]